# How to get rid of "" object name and working in loop?

Tags: r, loops

I do not know how to precisely define this problem; but I could not figure this out

```
    genx <- list(scaffold_1 = c("AAATTTTTATAT"),scaffold_2 = c("AAATTTTTATAT"),
    scaffold_3 = c("AAATTTTTATAT"),scaffold_4 = c("AAATTTTTATAT"),
    scaffold_5 = c("AAATTTTTATATA"),scaffold_6 = c("AAATTTTTATAT"),
scaffold_7 = c("AAATTTTTATAT"),scaffold_8 = c("AAATTTTTATATA"))


TATA = "TATA"   
      myobs <- paste("genx$scaffold_", 1:8, sep = "")
```

I want to apply the following function to every elments of the elements of myobs (are objects):

```
source("http://www.bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")

biocLite("Biostrings")
require((Biostrings)

countPattern (TATA, genx$scaffold_1, max.mismatch = 1)
[1] 3
```

When I use the following:

```
countPattern (TATA, myobs[1], max.mismatch = 1)
```

Doesnot work as it is I believe interpreted as:

```
countPattern (TATA, "genx$scaffold_1", max.mismatch = 1)
 [1] 0
```

Which is not same as the above one. How can get rid of "" and create a loop to perform this job, your suggestions are appreciated:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly use the list and do an `sapply` which acts on every element of the list. Here is some sample code

```
sapply(genx, countPattern, pattern = TATA, max.mismatch = 1)
```

Comment: Please note that this solution is giving value like:           countPattern (TATA, "genx$scaffold_1", max.mismatch = 1) 
 [1] 0  but my expected is [1] 3 ......which is result of   countPattern (TATA, genx$scaffold_1, max.mismatch = 1)

Comment: I tried this option again in fresh window but getting my answer ! surprising ...I can not tell what happend ...sorry for that ... thank both for the help ...

Comment: glad that it worked. @Tomas's answer is a little more transparent than mine. so i would be completely fine if you wanted to go ahead and accept his answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `get` function

```
a  <- 12
get("a") # returns 12
```

Comment: thanks for the help ...but I could get botton on how to deploy this function ..my limited R knowledge ...

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
sapply(genx, function (x) { countPattern(TATA, x, max.mismatch = 1) })
```

Comment: @Ramnath, are you sure? The key argument is at the second position, so I think you cannot write it as `sapply(genx, countPattern, pattern = TATA, max.mismatch = 1)`. Isn't the John's complaint related to this?

Comment: don't think it should matter, since the other parameters are identified by name. i can't install `biostrings`, so can you run the code i have and tell me what output it provides?

Comment: Sorry guys, when I intially pasted Ramnath codes I got all 0 results, but now in fresh window it works ...I am not sure about difference in codes ...thank both of you for the help ...

Comment: @Ramnath, thanks for teaching me something new, I didn't know it can work like this! Great! I find your solution more elegant than mine. John, feel free to accept Ramnath's answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with:

```
get("genx$scaffold_1")
```

because R thinks you are looking for an object with that full name, not the 'scaffold_1' component of 'genx'.

What should work is:

```
eval(parse(text="genx$scaffold_1"))
```

But see:

```
fortune(106)
```

More trouble spots along these lines can be found in 'The R Inferno': http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you define `genx$scaffold` as vector, and then you can easily use the apply function:

```
genx = data.frame(scaffold = c(1, 2, 3, 4)) # genx$scaffold is a vector
```

Now you can easily run the `countPattern()` function on every genx$scaffold's element

```
apply(as.matrix(genx$scaffold), 1, 
    function (x) { countPattern(TATA, x, max.mismatch = 1) })
```

You can easily extend the solution so that genx$scaffold can be also matrix etc.

Comment: please see my improved version of the question, I do not have luxery of changing genx..scaffold_1 to scaffold_8 can not be seperated ... thanks for the help ..

Comment: then use the `get()` solution posted by Karsten. But I'd still recommend to transform the list to simple vector. It will simplify you a lot of future tasks!